# Endless loop validating NSTableViewRow

Tags: nstableview

So I tried this code in both `shouldSelectRow` notification as well as `selectionShouldChange` function

I've just entered data in a row and trying to validate it. If invalid want to ask user if want to continue editing or let the selected row change, at which point I will refresh to keep the last (i.e. "new") row of my table blank. Problem is if I say "Yes" it keeps asking me question again and again because the method gets called again and again. Why?
 let isNew = //lastRowInTable

```
    if isNew {
        let check = validateRowAt(tableView.selectedRow)
        if check.error {
            let keep = shouldContinueEditing(check.message)
            if !keep {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else {
                tableView.editColumn(Column.description.hashValue, row: tableView.selectedRow, with: nil, select: true)
            }
            return keep ? false : true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some additional information. I put some debug statements. What's happening is I"m getting shouldSelectRow / selectionShouldChange called for rowCount -1 times. It is not infinite loop. Now why is this? Method should be called ONCE only because selection is not changing when user says "yes"

Comment: Yet more information. If I hardcode user response to "yes" without showing an Alert to accept response, I don't see a problem. So obtaining user response is somehow messing things up causing repeated (and bogus!) calls to each of the remaining rows asking if they should be selected. I have to say "Yes" on Alert box rowCount - 1 times before I'm returned back to editing the row.